# Bash script cannot list file in a directory. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: raspbian, bash

Here is my script, as simple as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/pi/watch-dir/*.torrent; do
   echo "$file"
   sleep 2
done
```

Base on this answer [How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash?answertab=votes#tab-top) I believe the for-in should see `/home/pi/watch-dir/*.torrent` as a list.

Inside the `watch-dir` directory:

```
pi@raspberry:~/watch_dir $ ls -al
total 68
drwxrwx---  2 pi pi  4096 Sep 15 18:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 pi pi  4096 Sep 15 19:03 ..
-rwxrwx---  1 pi pi 19065 Sep 15 18:59 asdf.torrent
-rwxrwx---  1 pi pi 19065 Sep 15 18:59 qwer.torrent
-rwxrwx---  1 pi pi 19065 Sep 15 18:59 zxcv.torrent
```

And this is the only-one-line-output after run the scipt, I really don't know what I am doing wrong...

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ./test.sh
/home/pi/watch-dir/*.torrent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got `watch-dir` in your loop and `watch_dir` is the folder!

```
- != _
```

Comment: The loop 'watch-dir' contains a minus character. The actual folder 'watch_dir' contains an underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously nothing related to Raspberry Pi but to Linux and Bash scripting.

The for-in operator operates on a space separated (line separated? You can change it with `IFS=<your separator>`) lists.

```
IFS=" "
for x in alice bob cindy d e f; do
  echo $x
done
```

will output

```
alice
bob
cindy
...
```

There is no globbing or thatsoever. So instead of your glob you will have to get a listing of the actual files. Something like `$(find . -type f -name "*.torrent")`

So you should be able to achieve your intent with

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find /home/pi/watch-dir -type f -name "*.torrent"); do
   echo "$file"
   sleep 2
done
```

`$(ls *.torrent)` should also work if you run the script from within the same directory or change into the dirctory within your script.

Comment: Base on this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash?answertab=votes#tab-top) I think the for-in should see `/home/pi/watch-dir/*.torrent` as a list right?